# How to trigger events in java at specific date and time?

Tags: java, crontrigger

I need to send sms to few mobile nos at specific date and time. e.g. I will have a list of dates and times and list of corresponding mobile nos. as below.

```
Date                Mobile
10th April 9 AM     1234567890
10th April 11 AM    9987123456,9987123457
11th April 3.30 PM  9987123456
```

and so on.

I know, java has cron schedulers which can run at specific schedule.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

I can run a job which can keep on checking the time and then if the current time matches with time in above list, send the sms.

But in this case I will have to keep on checking all the time.

Is there any way, i can fire those events/sms directly at given time. Something like registering jobs for each of the date time and firing those at that time instead of having a job that runs continuously to check for date times ?

Comment: How many events are we talking about? The best solution depends on the number of events you expect to fire per unit of time.

Comment: At one given date time, there will be one event only.

Comment: How many will be in the system waiting at a time to fire? The Java Timer will work up to a point.

Comment: I might have 10-20 such events waiting to fire overall on 10-20 different date time combination.

Comment: Go with the Java Timer class mentioned below in that case.

Comment: @Jason The Timer class documentation explains that the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework should be used instead of that class.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was asking him the scale for this exact reason. For the numbers he is talking about the Timer class is a very straight forward and well documented implemented with lots of examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

```
 private class SmsSenderTask implement Runnable {
     private String text;
     private List<String> phoneNumbers;

     public void run() {
         for (String number : phoneNUmbers) {
             sendSms(number, text);
         }
     }
}

ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
for (Date d : dates) {
    long millis = d.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    service.schedule(new SmsSenderTask(text, phoneNumbers), millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

The [Answer by Tulupov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43290120/642706) using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is correct and should be accepted. Here I address the date-time angle.

If possible, serialize your date-time values to text using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

> 2017-04-10T09:00:00Z
>
> 2017-04-10T11:00:00Z
>
> 2017-04-11T15:30:00Z

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing and generating date-time values.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2017-04-10T09:00:00Z" );
```

Also, you ignore the critical issue of time zones. The `Z` on my strings above are short for `Zulu` and mean UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

If you must work with strings in those unfortunate formats, search Stack Overflow for the `DateTimeFormatter` class to learn more on parsing strings.

If your date-times are meant for some other region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), then assign a time zone via `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow for those class names to learn much more.

You need to get a number of milliseconds to schedule the event with `ScheduledExecutorService`. You must calculate the number of milliseconds between the current moment and the desired `Instant` of the event. Such a span of time is represented by the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class as a total number of seconds plus a fractional second in nanoseconds. You can ask the `Duration` for its total span of time as a count of milliseconds (truncating any microseconds/nanoseconds).

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Duration d = Duration.of( now , instant ) ;
long millis = d.toMillis();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Timer class to schedule event at specific time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, java.util.Date)

```
timer.schedule(new DateTimeTask(), date);
```

Cons of this approach is it creates the list of multiple TimerTask. So performance depends on the number of tasks you want to schedule.

Comment: No. of events at max will be like 10-20. Is there any to pass data to events, e.g. I will need to pass mobile nos and few other data while sending the sms.

Comment: You can extend the TimerTask class and pass the require parameters in constructor. Just ensure to cancel the timer after sending the message,

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing some form of Custom Event Handler with call back methods registered  for each time. From your job you can kick in each call back method when the timer for each event reaches.